# Organisational Wiki

Tags: sharepoint, wiki, project-organization

I have been tasked at work with creating an organisational wiki to document information such as Employees, Teams (Groups of employees), and Systems (what we support) within MS Sharepoints Wiki Product. **Does anyone else have a Wiki for this information? What sort of roadblocks have you run into?**

I couldn't really find any nuggets of information about a corporate internal wiki, as these things tend to be internalized and not really discussed. The main goals I have are to

- Define Who we are (as an IT organisation)
- Define the systems we support
- Define the history/evolution of those systems

The initial goals are more about information associated with the organisation, not necessarily technical documentation or code samples for developers. I think I can draw that distinct line, I'll be okay with Sharepoint's Wiki Product. **Is there any other information that other organisations consider for this type of project?** We have a company intranet, but this will supplement and tell the story of the IT side of the organisation.